# windows copy of files / folders

Tags: windows, copy, directory

stupid question perhaps, but addressing a 40 year old stupid OS... I have a RAID6 array on a server which contains some 8TB in one partition. This is the Ubuntu box. I then have a Win 7 box, whereby I have 12TB in 6x2TB drives.

I am trying to copy the folders from ubuntu RAID6 to Windows 7, but as follows:

Drive 1 of Win 7 contains all folders A to D, drive 2 contains E to G, etc.

I started the copy / back up but then I had Windows reboot (thank you!) due to automatic updates installed. Having turned this off, I now want to restart the copy, but of course, the very smart Windows copy routine tells me there is not enough space on the destination drive to copy all A to D folders as it checks for space without consideration of duplicate / existing files at destination... so the only way I can see is to erase all copied folders and start again... bloody stupid.

I have tried Robocopy, FastCopy, SimpleCopy but I cannot get a piece of SW that can just copy the MISSING / NON EXISTENT files in the destination drive. Some of these programs do not even let me select Folders A - D...

How can I copy the missing files only, without having Win 7 check for available space before starting the process?

Comment: Use robocopy. The trick is not to include A-D folders, but to exclude (/xd switch) E-F folders from the copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that there is a way. Have you looked at SyncToy. It is an MS software and might be able to help you with that. The other thing that you can do; assuming you are using some sort of smb copy and not ftp or anything; why not mount the windows drive on the linux box and do the coping on the linux box rather than on the windows box?